# Unable to process same GET request multiple times. How do I get around this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web-services, express

I'm making a Node.JS app where the user sends commands to a robot.  These requests are received from Angular.JS $http.get() requests.  This is what the code looks like server side:

```
app.get('/control/:dir/:amount', function(req, res){
    var dir = req.params.dir.substring(1);
    var amount = req.params.amount.substring(1);
    networking.sendCommand(dir, amount);
});
```

I know everything is sent properly, but it can only process a certain request once (so no matter how many time localhost:8080/control/forward/100 is sent, it only gets processed once).  Is there any way around this?

Edit: The error was fixed by changing app.get() to app.post() and adding a res.sendStatus(200) back to the client.

Comment: Welcome to the world of caching. You need to set no cache header or use Verbs that do not cache.

Comment: Sticking with `get` requests may make it particularly hard to avoid caching, because those aren't _supposed_ to change state. `post` or other HTTP verbs may be more natural.

Comment: just to clarify these, changing to post didn't make it work, but the `res.sendStatus(200)` did, you need to return something, it's http if you have a request you need to provide a response.